# Call ajax HTTP to API with Sinatra

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, http, sinatra

I'm calling a service from my api built with sinatra, and I make a simple ajax call as I mention it below:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function (){
        seeStatus()
    });
    function seeStatus(){
        token = $('#token').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/see/v1/status/' + token,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "script",
            complete: function (response) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                if (json.error == 0) {
                    window.location.href = json.href
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

made a GET call and the server receives a call OPTIONS

```
190.141.191.102 - - [08/Mar/2018:12:31:38 +0000] "OPTIONS /see/v1/status/f4dce2eb193674cab37ff36cbaca2eb4c0355165?_=1520512306539 HTTP/1.1" 404 51 0.0133
```

The code of my service is not executed from the ajax method and I do not understand why? , when I try my service independently with an HTTP client it works correctly What can I do? Any help Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the network traffic header data how the calls differ between your HTTP Client and your code? It might be the way you append the token?

Comment: I'm going to check, you're right, the error may be there

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're having an issue with **CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)**. It would be interesting to know where the script requesting the API and where the API itself are located. I guess they're not on the same server.

In a nutshell, CORS is a mechanism that prevents a resource on one domain to freely access a resource on another domain. Your webpage can load resource on its own domain (scripts, stylesheets, fonts, json, etc.) but by default, Javascript HTTP requests (XMLHttpRequest / fetch) use the same-origin policy by default, which means they can only request resources on the same domain.

According to [the CORS dedicated page on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Functional_overview), here's the reason for the OPTIONS request you see on the server side:

> the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS request method"

---

I guess you'll have to configure CORS on your server, or make it so that the HTML file calling the API is located on the same domain as the API itself (which might not be possible).

Since you used the Sinatra tag in this question, I guess your server is written in Sinatra, in that case you can use the [britg/sinatra-cross_origin](https://github.com/britg/sinatra-cross_origin) gem to setup CORS rule on your API server.